# Using the apply function in combination with the shift function

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to iterate thru a dataframe. My goal would be to increase the value in the column `loop` when in the column `rpm` the previous row and the actual row aren't equal.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'rpm': [5000, 5000, 10000, 10000, 15000, 15000], 
                    'temp': [23, 23, 24, 23, 24, 25]})
df['loop'] = 0

def loop_no(x,y):
    if x.rpm != y.rpm:
        val = y.loop + 1
    else:
        val = x.loop
    return val

df['loop'] = df.apply(lambda x: loop_no(x, x.shift(-1)))
```

At this point, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: ("'Series' object has no attribute 'rpm'", u'occurred at index rpm').
```

When I use `axis=1`, I don't get an error. But obviously it shifts then in column direction. So, I don't get the previous line.

```
df['loop'] = df.apply(lambda x: loop_no(x, x.shift(-1)), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
(df.rpm!=df.rpm.shift(-1)).cumsum()
Out[796]: 
0    0
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    3
Name: rpm, dtype: int32
```

More info

```
df['loop']=(df.rpm!=df.rpm.shift(-1)).cumsum()
df
Out[799]: 
     rpm  temp  loop
0   5000    23     0
1   5000    23     1
2  10000    24     1
3  10000    23     2
4  15000    24     2
5  15000    25     3
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works great. But, I don't understand why my way doesn't work. Is it not possible to iterate like I did?

Comment: @StephanF. apply is base on row, which mean , every time your function received one lane data, they do not have shift here. or their shift always be NaN, if you do need something like your function you can consider `for loop`

Comment: That makes it clear. I tried to avoid `iteritems` since it is very slow.